# Use Webkit as browser control in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, webkit, vb.net-2010, webkit.net

I'm developing an application where I want to use WebKit browser engine instead IE browser control, and I'm looking for latest version of WebKit which is currently behind Google Chrome 10, so far, I found WebKit.Net but it was updated a while ago, so not all modern HTML5 and CSS3 capabilities are working with it. Is there any other option available for WebKit to be used with the application. I don't know how to build WebKit from source so that it can work with VB.Net.

Also, will it support JavaScript if included in the form??

Comment: even if it hasn't been updated in a while, webkit.net is still going to be orders of mangitude better than the IE8-based engine you've got currently.

Comment: @Spudley: After few tweaks, I've managed to use WebKit.Net wrapper with latest Nightly build of WebKit.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: the question is yet not answered.

Comment: @Kush - You can answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

Bad news friend, at the date, WebKit.Net doesn't support COM intraction between .Net and the COM objects in the HTMLDocument,